# The same sql query in php my admin gives me deferent results in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code

```
SELECT * from bills INNER JOIN bills_categories ON bills.id = bills_categories.bill_id
```

When I use this SQL query in MySQL PHPmyadmin it gives me the correct results but when I use the same structure in laravel 8 it gives me different results. this is the query builder code in laravel

```
public function index()
{
    $bill = DB::table('bills')
        ->join('bills_categories', 'bills.id', '=', 'bills_categories.bill_id')
        ->get();
    return $bill;
}
```

that's what I got with MySQL phpmyadmin

[image]

and that's what I got with laravel

[image]

You can see that the results in laravel were wrong.

Comment: note: when trying to make that join using another column, not the primary key column in laravel It works correctly.

Comment: Both are the same result. one has `select *` (phpmyadmin) and the other has `select bills.*` laravel.

Answer (score -1):

Of course. Why? easy :)

Because on the frist query you have an inner join and on the second, you have a left join

Comment: No also when using inner join It gives the same results.

Comment: `->join()` is `INNER JOIN`

Comment: no, I had a typo at first but I edited it.

Comment: I don't know who give me -1 vote. At the moment I answer to the question, the problem was, wgat i wrote.